# Create variable threshold line in timeseries (Community Version)

Tags: thingsboard

I would like to set a threshold line in a diagram based on an attribute.
I configured some variable server attributes. The threshold line should change according to this value.

It is possible to use an attribute by the "Value taken from entity attribute" function.
How do I configure an entity attribute?

I am using the community version.

Thank you in advance.
Thomas
[picture of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7xmo.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for the problem.

One solution is to get the attributes by an "originator attributes" node, then set the attribute values from metadata to msg and safe them at the end.

```
msg.max_temp = metadata.ss_max_temp;
msg.min_temp = metadata.ss_min_temp;

return {msg: msg, metadata: metadata, msgType: msgType};
```

CREDITS: https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/issues/672#issuecomment-524652104
That's it.